# Mullers method with c rule alwayes print NaN

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I am trying to apply the Mullers Method through Java , The Rule says that I have variable B : This variable B will be used the Sign ( - , + ) in the C Rule

In the c rule , I must use the variable B sign like this : 
[image]

but i have a problem : the cmd print "NaN" >> not a number just when the c result is Negative

i think the sign it is the main problem and this is my code for C : `

```
 if( B_value() > 0 ) // Positive Sign +
{

   double x =   X2_float -  ( 2 * number2 ) / ( B_value() + ( Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B_value(),2) - 4 * A_value() * number2   ) )     );
    t = (float) x;

}

else
{
    double x =    X2_float -  ( 2 * number2 ) / ( B_value() - ( Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B_value(),2) - 4 * A_value() * number2   ) )     );
    t = (float) x;

}
```

Comment: Standard Java Math.sqrt cannot handle square roots of negative numbers. It will return NaN. The argument of your sqrt (b**2 - 4ac) is likely negative in those cases, check that first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , yes the Argument is Negative , how I can resolve this problem ? The result is correct in few of cases , another cases result NaN

Comment: I have idea and please help me if you have Suggestions .. I can check if the result of sqrt is NaN .. I can use method Math.abs that mean if the sqrt result is like -12 .. after I use math.abs the result will be 12 and then I can Multiple 12 * -12 .. that is the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Java Math.sqrt cannot handle square roots of negative numbers. It will return NaN.

Mathematically the square root of a negative real number is a complex number. If a quadratic discriminant (b**2 -4ac) is negative, mathematically, its square root should be treated as a complex number. Doing something else would be an error. In the case of Muller's method, you are trying to find roots of an equation, and you need to know if the roots are expected to be real or complex.

If you want to work with real numbers/real roots only and java.Math only, a negative argument should be treated as an error condition.

If you want to work with complex numbers you need to use a Java library that supports sqrt() and other operations on complex numbers, such as Apache Commons Math.

Comment: Thanks a lot , there is API that calculate Sqrt can I use it ?

Comment: Look up documents on Apache Commons Math online for complex numbers. This will get you started: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/index.html